# Can't upload Adobe Air iOS app in Appstore

Tags: ios, air, adobe, distribute

It's not my first time to upload an app to AppStore but this time I faced uncommon situation.

When I try to upload my app to Appstore it gives me this error:

**"ERROR : "Invalid Code Signing. The executable 'Payload/رأس گیر چک سایه.app/رأس گیر چک سایه' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile."**

I tried this solutions:

- I'm recreated my distribution cert and provisioning profile 3 times.
- I tried both Application Loader 3.0 and 3.1
- I tried OSx 10.6 and 10.9
- I checked privated keys for exporting .p12 cert.
- I checked my time zone and mac clock.
- I'm tested Air 18, Air 19 and Air 21.

I got confused. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had signing issues which ended up being caused by expired Apple certificates being present in my Keychain.

So check for and delete any expired certificates within Keychain Access before creating a certificate signing request and exporting the .p12 file and regenerating the provisioning profile.

[image: Expired Apple certs]